# ServiceStack: Cannot access a disposed stream on IRequiresRequestStream

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am a new ServiceStack user and currently evaluating its potential.

My question is:

I have:

```
[Route("/register/event")]
public class EventRequestStream : IRequiresRequestStream
    {
        public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    }
```

and then

```
public void Any(EventRequestStream payload)
        {
             RegisterEventRequest[] batch = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream< RegisterEventRequest[]>(payload.RequestStream);  

        }
```

This throws a Cannot access a disposed stream.

You will notice in the example above that what I really wanted to do is:

```
public void Any(RegisterEventRequest[] payload)
        {

        }
```

But I get a Null Reference Exception. If I remove the [] (and pass the relevant JSON) then its fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Every Request DTO in ServiceStack needs to be a uniquely named concrete class.

If you're only looking to send a collection of DTO's you can just inherit from `List<T>`, e.g:

```
[Route("/register/event")]
public class RegisterEvents : List<RegisterEvent> {}
```

The `Any(T[])` can only be used in [AutoBatched Requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Batched-Requests).